# How import WebApplicationBuilder in a Class Library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to create an extension method for WebApplicationBuilder:

```cs
public static void AddData(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
    {
        option.UseSqlite(connectionString);
    });
}
```

this method works in a project that use: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`,
but if I put this method in a class libary then it doesn't work (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk>`) because it doesn't find `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder`

Otherwise, if I use `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` the compiler say that there is no Main in the project.

How can I do?

Why can't I write this?

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem but [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) explains what you need to do.

Add

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

to your .csproj and you can then use

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
```

in your regular class library which targets `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`.

Comment: Thank you, I had a base startup class in a shared web class library and when I added the normal <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> into the csproj file it would complain about there being no static main method, so your suggestion sorted this out for me!

Answer (score 3):

I did this recently when I converted to a .Net 6 project.  I wasn't able to extend the Builder either, so I added the extension to the IServiceCollection and passed in the configuration.  So to use your example, my code looked more like:

```
public static void AddData(this IServiceCollection services, ApplicationSettings appSettings)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
    {
        option.UseSqlite(appSettings.ConnectionString);
    });
}
```

Where ApplicationSettings is a custom class that is bound to the app settings in the json.  So my Program.cs has these lines:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

var appSettings = new ApplicationSettings();
configuration.Bind(appSettings);
builder.Services.AddData(appSettings);
```

Using the IServiceCollection in the extension method only requires:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Comment: You can reference AspNetCore types in a regular class library, you just need to add a framework reference (see my answer below). (From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)